# POST requests not working in Swift with Alamofire

Tags: php, ios, swift, post, alamofire

I'm trying to send data from a Swift app to a backend in PHP.
To test, I make a request via POST with Alamofire and print the request method as a response from the Server.

```swift
let URL_USER = "myurl"
var sampleRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: URL_USER)!)
sampleRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
            
AF.request(sampleRequest).uploadProgress{ progress in }.response(){
    response in
    if(response.data != nil) {
        print(String(bytes: response.data!, encoding: .utf8) as Any)
    }
    else {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

The PHP script:

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo 'OK';
}
else {
    echo 'Wrong request method';
}
```

The server response is always `Wrong request method`

The same also occurs using the post parameter directly inside the Alamofire call, with this code:

```swift
AF.request("myurl", method: .post).response {...}
```

Any attempt to send the request via POST, even without Alamofire, fails and the server replies saying that the request is of type GET.

This occurs both on the simulator and on a real device, without any proxy.

The URL I call is based on https

**UPDATE**
To test the basic functioning of Alamofire with the function of their documentation I tried this code:

```swift
AF.request(URL_USER, method: .post).response {
    response in
    if(response.data != nil) {
        print(String(bytes: response.data!, encoding: .utf8) as Any)
    }
    else {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

But the response still goes `Wrong request method` and Proxyman says it's of type GET

Comment: Use a proxy of some kind to inspect the actual traffic being sent to see if the method is actually an issue.

Comment: @JonShier Using Proxyman I see the method used is GET, so the error is in the iOS client

Comment: I didn't use alamofire in years, but I doubt you could provide a method like you do. So it would use `get` as a default. Instead try to follow syntax on their Introduction (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#introduction): `AF.request(URL_USER, method: .post))

Comment: @NiccolòSegato Strange. Is there a redirect in the middle of this process? URLSession will reset redirected requests to GET sometimes.

Comment: @rapiddevice I've already tried setting .post as the parameter for method in the call, but it still doesn't work. Even following the code of the official documentation remains GET as a request.

Comment: @JonShier The server is written by me so I'm sure I haven't entered any redirects. Making a POST request to the same address from Postman or similar works smoothly. I wonder if there is a setting somewhere in the Xcode project or something similar

Comment: But did you try `AF.request(URL_USER, method: .post)` (that is: the most basic form of the request, without creating `URLRequest`)? Unless Alamofire has a bug (and they don't - hundreds of apps using them), that should create a `POST` request to the server. You can also monitor what Alamofire is about to send (like this: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#logging) That way you can proof or exclude one side of the problem.

Comment: @rapiddevice I've updated the post with the attempt you suggested. I had already done that but just to be safe I ran it again. The result is always a GET request.

Comment: Does the PHP code detect correctly a POST with a `cURL` or using POSTMAN (or any other similar solution)? If yes, could it be because there is no `httpBody`?

Comment: @Larme I tried `AF.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)` but, again, GET is the result
With Postman and Thunder Client the PHP script detect POST correctly.

Comment: @JonShier You were right! Apparently there is a redirect, I believe due to DNS resolution. On iOS, I called `https://mysite.tld` and it was redirected with GET to `https://www.mysite.tld`. However, this was not the case with other clients such as Postman.

Comment: @NiccolòSegato Yeah, `URLSession` (which underlies Alamofire) has some odd behavior here. You can customize your redirect handling using Alamofire's `.redirect` modifier to see when redirects occur and control whether or not they're followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a redirect in the URL.
For some reason `https://mysite.tld` was redirecting to `https://www.mysite.tld` using GET. In this way all the parameters and the type of request were altered. I solved the problem by making the request directly to `https://www.mysite.tld`.
To find out the redirect I used Proxyman.